# Wordpress admin area search bug "invalid post type"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm noticing a strange bug across several Wordpress sites and was wondering who else has experienced it - and how they solved it, ideally!

If I click All Pages and search for anything it works fine. If I try to search again from the results page, though, it spits out an "invalid post type" error.

The solution has been to click to view All Posts and start again - but there must surely be a fix?

Thanks!
G

Answer (score 5):

For me the was issue was with the active theme, search in your functions.php code like 'pre_get_posts' , then you will see something like:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_posts' );
```

You must replace it with:

```
if(!is_admin()) {
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_posts' );
}
```

For me it helped, but before this try to turn off plugins one by one to be sure that the problem was not from the plugins side.

Comment: Brilliant note. Should be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like conflict with some plugin or your theme: clean WordPress does not have this bug.

To debug, disable all plugins and check if it will be fine then. If it fixes your issue, start to enable plugins one by one to find "guilty" (you can use [divide and conquer strategy](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) to speed up this)

What do you have in url of page, when you see your error? It should have:

> ...&post_type=page&...

Do you have it?

Comment: I just checked and can confirm it's relating to this - the original (working) value passes:

    &post_type=post

The broken one passes:

    &post_type=Array

So therein lies my problem. Will this definitely be a plugin issue?

Comment: plugin or theme. something substitutes your post type to array (actually something passes array here and it is typecasted to string "Array").

disabling plugins and themes one by one will help you to find the guilty. then we will know how to troubleshoot it

Comment: Just checking prior to culling the plugins - I'm noticing the query string seems to concatenate exponentially - each time I search, extra strings are added instead of replacing existing. So even in my incorrect query string with post_type=Array, I have an additional string containing post_type=All

Comment: well, it is still not helpfull as long as we don't know which plugin is guilty (or theme) :)